# PHP Sublime Text Use Find and Replace Regular Expression

Tags: php, replace, find, expression

I got a problem, i need to search and replace some words 
Here is an example :

```
$num = $enreg1["num"];
$daterecep = $enreg1["date_recep"];
```

And I want at the end :

```
$num = $enreg1->num;
$daterecep = $enreg1->date_recep;
```

Then i wrote this regular expression :

```
enreg[1-9]?\["[\w]+"]
```

It's working fine, i find all my word like I Want but the problem is when I want to replace what I found.
Because I just want to replace the [" by ->   and   "] by nothing.

If someone know how is working Sublime Text for replace !

Thanks for your help !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add parenthesis in your regular expression to get matched values, like this:

```
(enreg[1-9]?)\["([\w]+)"]
```

Then, you can retrieve this values using *$x* in the replace input ($1 for the first value, $2 for the second...).

In your case, you will have to use the following replace pattern :

```
$1->$2
```

For the first line, $1 will be replaced by "enreg1" and $2 by "num" so you will have:

```
$num = $enreg1->num;
```